# Reach to the extreme of font size in one step

Tags: fonts

Usually to view the org or code in a bird view, I will decrease the font size to the extreme of minimal with M-x decrease, C-x z, z, z, z until reach the extreme.

Is it possible to reach the extremes of minimal or max in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new function that minimize the font size and bound it to an unused keybinding.

```
(defun my-text-scale-minimize ()
  (interactive)
  (text-scale-increase (text-scale-min-amount)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c -") #'my-text-scale-minimize)
```

If the font size is too small replace `(text-scale-min-amount)` with a negative integer.

To restore the original size use the built in keybinding `C-x C-0`.